# Out of Range exception when removing duplicates from Array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, do-while

I have created an Array of 36 random numbers between 1-49. I have nested a do-while loop inside of the for loop that inserts the numbers into the array to remove any duplicate numbers. When running the code to test I get an exception
**"System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"**

```
{
            Random rand = new Random();

            int[] Numbers = new int[36];
            
            for (int r = 0; r <= 36; r++)
            {
                int nextValue;
                do
                {
                    nextValue = rand.Next(1, 50);
                } while (Numbers.Contains(nextValue));

                Numbers[r] = nextValue;
            }

            return Numbers;

        }
```

**Numbers[r] = nextValue;** caused the exception.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Perhaps because you allocated 36 values for Number, but r goes up to 49.

Comment: `r` goes up to 49, but your array only goes up to 36.

Comment: I have changed this and updated the value however it is still throwing the exception

Comment: There is an easier way to exclude duplicates...and it is just one line

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Can you explain, or point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: try this => for (int r = 0; r < 36; r++)

Comment: I have already updated my code to show that. However, the exception is still occuring

Comment: check the condition r<36

Comment: I replied to the answer. I didn't realise I had <= still I was meant to remove the = when the value was changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initialise your numbers array with 36 spaces

```
Numbers = new int[36];
```

But inside your loop, you assign to number is place up to 49

```
 for (int r = 0; r <= 49; r++)
.....
Numbers[r] = nextValue;
```

Your loop max value should be changed to 36, it is not related to the maximum value you require from the Random generation

Comment: That's my mistake I have changed  the value to 36 however I am still getting the error

Comment: I'm clearly blind didn't notice the <=. Thanks just a simple mistake on my part